# Limit on open nettcpbinding connections

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

So I realize this is a pretty loaded question, but here's what I'm trying to gauge.

I've got a server that accepts reliable-session tcp connections via WCF and opens a callbackchannel to the client.  99.999% of the time, it's just connected, waiting for the server to issue a callback (not actively processing anything, just maintaining the connection).

What kind of per machine bottlenecks will I hit?  I've already handled WCF `<servicethrottling />` attributes on the binding, but just from a load/max connection/"anything else I'm missing" standpoint, I'm trying to get a sense of how many clients can be served per Azure Small Instance given that by and large, these guys will be sitting idly by, just waiting.

Comment: +1 Good question - not necessarily a good design, but a good question. Genuine, non-prescriptive-design related answers will be interesting.

Comment: Yeah I'd certainly consider different designs, although low latency response is a design requirement so I'd expect that'd preclude some mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're opening outbound connections, you'll want to consider increasing

`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`

in your role OnStart() code. I can't recall the default, but I *believe* it's 12.

While you're at it, might as well consider setting

`ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm`

to `false` if you push lots of short messages (under, oh, 1400 bytes). Otherwise the messages get buffered up to a half-second. I gave a bit more detail on Nagle in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8954906/272109).

Comment: Good advice!  I had the `DefaultConnectionLimit` addressed, but I hadn't considered the Nagle algorithm. If I will have calls of varied size, some less than 1400, some larger, do I lose a lot of efficiency on the larger calls if using Nagle?

Comment: With larger packets, you won't be affected by Nagle.